# Gravity forms multi-step anchor offset

Tags: php, gravity-forms-plugin

I'm using gravity forms in order to create a three step form. Once you click on the next button the form loads the new page then automatically scrolls back down to the form. This is fine however I have a sticky header of about 100px so it's scrolling a bit too far past the form.

My question is: Is there an offset I can add to the gform_confirmation_anchor in order to offset for my sticky header.

Here is the code I have tried that is in the Gravity Forms documentation:
https://docs.gravityforms.com/gform_confirmation_anchor/

```
add_filter( 'gform_confirmation_anchor_5', function() {
    return 20;
} );
```

Essentially this only allows for you to scroll to 20px from the top (however I couldn't get this working).

What I require is to offset the scroll by about 100px.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Any luck finding the answer? I got the same problem...

Comment: I didn't find an answer to this issue, instead I did a workaround and used ajax to load the form instead of navigating to a new page. [gravityform id=1 ajax=true] I'm unsure if this will help you or not depending on your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

A workaround is to add top padding (CSS) to the form tag which has the anchor attached to it to create the offset. Padding-top: 50px for example, if the extra space bothers you, you can remove it with margin-top: -50px; with the offset still working.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem and was searching for a solution. I've only tested this with Gravity Forms 5, but it may work with other versions.

If you have a fixed header, the math that tells the window to "try" to locate at the top of the form will go too far.

```
add_filter( 'gform_confirmation_anchor', '__return_false', 100 );//hooked late to make sure we have the last say
```

Then, you need to add this JS (either printed inline, or added to a JS file that loads with your page):

```
    $(document).on( 'gform_post_render', function( event, formId, currentPage ){ 

        $(window).on( "load", function(){
           
            var headerHeight = $('.site-header').outerHeight(); //.site-header is my fixed header element. Replace with a class/id that corresponds to your site header
            
           $(this).scrollTop( $('#gform_wrapper_' + formId ).offset().top - headerHeight ); 

            
        });
    
                
    });
```

Hope this helps somebody else in the future!